# Username/passwd authentication in ADFS through WIF

Tags: c#, .net, wif, adfs2.0, adfs

I'm building a REST web service mobile apps authentication - take username and password, authenticate in ADFS (preferably through WIF if possible) and returns the SAML (2.0) token back to caller. It's used for authorization in later calls.
I found many guides and blog posts about authentication through WIF in web apps and authorization in WCF when the token is passed in call but I haven't found any clue how to approach this scenario. Any suggestions how to start?

Answer (score 2):

What is your mobile client built on? If you can use WIF (as in have the .NET platform available), then [WSTrustChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873343.aspx) is your friend.

> Note: with REST services you often use lighter-weight token formats, like JWT. This is what Azure Mobile Services uses as an example.

Comment: Mobile client is an iPad application (at least for now) so I'm afraid that the .Net solution would not be suitable here. This is the reason why I'm building an intermediary web service for this purpose. Regarding JWT/SWT tokens, unfortunately they are not available out-of-the-box in my FS infrastructure but I consider using Azure ACS for transformations so lighter-weight tokens are also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IdentityServer to mediate between the WS-Trust world and OAuth2/JWTs - see here:
http://brockallen.com/2013/04/14/getting-json-web-tokens-jwts-from-adfs-via-thinktecture-identityservers-adfs-integration/

Comment: Thank you for hint. Unfortunately there is quite big chance that I'll have to host the entire solution in environment where I won't be able to install anything more than my web service. It's extremely hard to convince sec auditors in my organization to use some 3rd party solutions...