# "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" exception when authenticating to ADFS

Tags: c#, wif, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

As I described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242712/username-passwd-authentication-in-adfs-through-wif/19264954) I build a web service that will take username/password and based on these credentials authenticate users (mobile apps) in ADFS2. My web service is configured as RP on the ADFS. ADFS issues SAML 2.0 tokens.

Here is a code of the web method:

```
public class MobileAuthService : IMobileAuthService
{
    private const string adfsBaseAddress = @"https://<my_adfs_hostname>/adfs/services/";
    private const string endpointSuffix = @"trust/13/issuedtokenmixedsymmetricbasic256";

    public string AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

        var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(adfsBaseAddress + endpointSuffix))
                                        {
                                            TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
                                        };
        trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;

        var tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue, KeyTypes.Symmetric);
        var token = tokenClient.Issue(rst);

        // do some token-related stuff

        return token.Id;
    }
}
```

When I try to run it (GET call from browser since it's configured with web http binding for this endpoint) I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException - "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail."
```

with inner exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException - "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
```

I guess it's related with the response signature or certificate but I have no idea how to overcome this since I'm quite new in WIF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to (partly) solve this issue. I've changes few things in my code, but the problems seems to be related with:

- STS endpoint -should be `/trust/13/usernamemixed` for this type of authentication
- RST key type - when I've set it `Bearer` it started returning a SAML token

Here is my most recent version:

```
public class MobileAuthService : IMobileAuthService
{
    private const string stsEndpointAddress = @"https://<my_adfs_hostname>/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed";

    private const string relyingPartyAddress =
        "https://<my_service_addr>/Auth.svc";

    public string AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var binding = new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential)
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
            };

        var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(stsEndpointAddress))
                                        {
                                            TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
                                        };

        var channelCredentials = trustChannelFactory.Credentials;
        channelCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        channelCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
        channelCredentials.SupportInteractive = false;

        var tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue, KeyTypes.Bearer)
            {
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(relyingPartyAddress),
                ReplyTo = relyingPartyAddress,
                TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0"
            };

        // to some token-related stuff (like transformations etc...)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help people who ends up with similar problem.